# How to make one function generate a uniquely named global variable on each call? javascript (no jquery)

Tags: javascript, function, variables

In part of a site I'm designing, the user will have an option to design a question which will have multiple properties (i.e. question text, name, answer value, etc.).

On the press of a button, I would like to call a function to store the properties of this question in an array.

However, the user can make multiple questions, and I need the array for each question to have a unique name, as they must be global arrays all available for later use.

That being said, I've researched and cant think of a way to make the same variable create differently named arrays depending on context.

Ideally I would like something that increments variable names, i.e. myArray1, myArray2, but have been unable to find such a thing.

Comment: Do not construct names for global variables. Instead, put what you were trying to call `myArray1` etc. into an master array called `myArrays`, as `myArrays[0]` etc.

Comment: that's what i wanted to do at first, but somehow thought I would have to name the array if i was going to put it inside another array. So i take it then that the solution is putting all properties of aa question in a specific array index, like array[0], and then incrementing the array index for each successive question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON for this instead of arrays

e.g. declare a variable like

var questions = [];

now create a json and add it to questions

```
questions.push({
questionText : "asdfasdfasdf",
name : "asdfasdf",
ans : "asdfasdf"
});
```

Now you can access the array like questions[0].name

Answer (score 0):

```
var myFn = (function() {
  var counter = 1;
  return function() {
    var ret = window['myArray' + counter] = [];
    counter++;
    return ret;
  };
})();
```

call myFn() will return an array and attach it to the global namespace.

Like others, I don't recommend doing this but it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than Array, use Object as a namespace for your global variable.

```
var myGlobalArray = {}
```

The object's properties can be called two ways:

```
myGlobalArray.prop //like typical object
myGlobalArray["prop"] //like an array
```

We can take benefit of latter style of accessing the property.

now in your code you can set

```
var myGlobalArray["myArray1"] = {
        "question" : "abcd efgh",
        "name": "sdas asdasda",
        "answer" : "value sdsd dvvsd"
    }
```

and

```
var myGlobalArray["myArray2"] = {
        "question" : "abcd efgh",
        "name": "sdas asdasda",
        "answer" : "value sdsd dvvsd"
    }
```

that can later be accessed by:

```
myGlobalArray["myArray1"], myGlobalArray["myArray2"], ....etc
```

or destroy them:

```
delete myGlobalArray["myArray2"];
```